# Need to reduce double line spacing

Tags: tables, line-spacing

[image]

```
\documentclass[two column,conference]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[!htp]
\setlength\extrarowheight{6pt}
\caption{}\label{title}
\centering
\begin{tabular}
{| >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.8in} || >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.1in} || >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.4in} || >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.2in}|}
 \hline
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

My question is I have used `\hline \hline` in order to make line double as shown in the table in fig. However, need to reduce space between double line i.e, spaces between `\hline` and `\hline`. and also to reduce space among vertical column line which "||". Thank you

Comment: Do you just want a thicker line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this style is not my favorite, you can use `hhline` from the package with the same name and change the dimension `doublerulesep` which is responsible for the distance between two vertical/horizontal lines. For example, you may choose `\setlength\doublerulesep{.5pt}`.

```
\documentclass[two column,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array,hhline}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!htp]
%\setlength\extrarowheight{6pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\setlength\doublerulesep{.5pt}
\caption{}\label{title}
\centering
\begin{tabular}
{| >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.8in} || >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.1in} || >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.4in} || >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.2in}|}
 \hhline{t:=:t:=:t:=:t:=:t}  
 Technique & Aim       & Distinctive attributes & Limitations \\ \hhline{----}
 Something & Something & Something              & Something \\ 
 \hhline{b:=:b:=:b:=:b:=:b}
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you AboAmmar !!! If I have table with tabular environment how I do that like I have code. I mean where I have to put these  lines
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\setlength\doublerulesep{.5pt}

\begin{center}
 \captionof{table}{GA parameters}\label{title}
 \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}||p{2cm}|}
  \hline
 \hline
 \textbf{\small Parameters}   & \textbf{\small values} \\
 \hline
 Maximum iteration &\rmfamily  200 \\
 Population size &\rmfamily 30\\
 $P_{c}$&\rmfamily 0.9 \\
 $P_{m}$ &\rmfamily 0.1\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

Comment: @Shane  If you need the new settings everywhere, put the two lines `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} \setlength\doublerulesep{.5pt}` in the preamble, if you want these settings for only the current `tabular` then put the two lines  after `\begin{center}` or use a pair `{}`. If you still have more queries feel free to open a new question for it.

Comment: I must say thank you for your help. But just elaborate one thing which is I got error on these two lines which please tell what I have to do for this \hhline{t:=:t:=:t:=:t:=:t} 
 \hhline{b:=:b:=:b:=:b:=:b}

Comment: You can remove them (the two `\hhline`s) and use the normal `\hline\hline` instead, no need for the `hhline` package, then. The output will be mostly the same, only minor differences at the intersections of double lines.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370777/double-line-become-one-and-thick-how-adjust-it?noredirect=1#370777
please come to my question and answer there as you told me.