# How do I stop double lines from becoming a single thick line

Tags: tables, line-spacing, rules

```
\begin{table*}[!htp]
\setlength\extrarowheight{6pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\setlength\doublerulesep{.5pt}
\caption{something}\label{title}
\centering
\begin{tabular}
{| >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} || >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.1in} || >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.4in} || >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.2in}|}
 \hline
 \hline
 \textbf{\small Techniques}   &  \textbf{\small Aim} & \textbf{\small Distinctive attributes} &  \textbf{\small Limitations} \\ %\midrule
 \hline
something \cite{8}&  something& something& something\\
\hline
```

[image]

I got an issue which is instead of double lines as other columns have I got single thick line please resolve it.

Comment: please fix your example to be a small complete document that shows the problem, the image posted is made from different code so doesn't really help. also you have tagged this with longtable and tabulary but the example does not use either?

Comment: it's impossible to tell from the fragments shown but is this just a viewer issue? what happens if you zoom in? you have made `\doublerulesep` very small, it may just vanish at some resolutions.

Comment: Dear David Carlisle! sorry about tagging wrong but the problem I showed is very clear as I need the first column line double by using above mention code I had got single thick line instead of double.

Comment: please fix the example so it can be run to produce the problem.

Comment: If the posted code is made into a proper document it produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx8wh.png) which has double vertical rules so any issue is in code not shown.

Comment: instead to bother with vertical lines ... consider package `booktabs` (for settings professional tables) and remove vertical lines in table!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known viewer issue. At some zoom levels you observe the effect you posted above and at other zoom levels you see different effects. Here is an example using the modified `doublerulesep` and the default one. The code is taken from [your previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370719/59109).

```
\documentclass[two column,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
%\setlength\extrarowheight{6pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\setlength\doublerulesep{.5pt}
\caption{something doublerulesep = 0.5pt}\label{title0}
\centering
\begin{tabular}
{| >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} || >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.1in} || >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.4in} || >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.2in}|}
 \hline
 \hline
 \textbf{\small Techniques}   &  \textbf{\small Aim} & \textbf{\small Distinctive attributes} &  \textbf{\small Limitations} \\ %\midrule
 \hline
something \cite{8}&  something& something& something\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htp]
%\setlength\extrarowheight{6pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
%\setlength\doublerulesep{.5pt}
\caption{something doublerulesep as default}\label{title1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}
{| >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in} || >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.1in} || >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.4in} || >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.2in}|}
 \hline
 \hline
 \textbf{\small Techniques}   &  \textbf{\small Aim} & \textbf{\small Distinctive attributes} &  \textbf{\small Limitations} \\ %\midrule
 \hline
something \cite{8}&  something& something& something\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

At another zoom level (160%) it appears as this:

[image]

Using `booktabs` package, however, gives this much better result:

```
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{table*}[!htp]
\caption{something with booktabs}\label{title1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{M{1in} M{1.1in} M{1.4in} M{1.2in}}
\toprule
\textbf{Techniques} & \textbf{Aim} & \textbf{Distinctive attributes} & \textbf{Limitations} \\ \midrule
something \cite{8}  & something    & something                       & something            \\
something \cite{8}  & something    & something                       & something            \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

[image]